# Vector Software for Drawing and Diagramming

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, graphics, drawing

What software is available for Mac that is good for drawing cartoons and diagrams?

These are some features it should have:

- Edit any component easily after drawing it.
- Easily add and edit text anywhere.
- Graphics Tablet support, preferably with a pressure-sensitive option.

Also it should be able to import/export:

- Import other image formats, and ideally should be able to convert hand-drawn images into vector images.
- Export into png and svg formats, and for extra credit, export a clickable image map.

**Extra Information:**
**Omnigraffle** looks good for diagramming (and can export clickable image maps), but it doesn't seem like its for drawing non-diagrams.
**EazyDraw** looked like it might combine some graphing and drawing features, but I'm not sure how stable it is.

What software is there that has the above drawing features and can do some diagramming?

Comment: there is a useful comparison on wikipedia where you can learn and contribute from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_editors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be difficult to get all features into one app but I'll suggest 5. They might have features in common but I'll highlight the ones you're asking about.

- **Artboard** - Tablet support
- **Sketch** - Imports/exports to SVG
- **Intaglio** - Diagramming
- **iVinci** - Converts from bitmap to vector
- **Pencil** - Tablet support (mostly suited for animation and cartoons with bitmap and vector drawing, onion skinning, etc.)

All of them should allow

- Editing any component easily after drawing it (layer support)
- Easily add and edit text anywhere (vectorized text is a standard)
- Exporting to PNG (also a standard)

I can't post more than 2 links but you'll find them easily on [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/) (all have trial downloads).

Comment: you should mention that sketch (now skencil) and pencil are not developed anymore...

Comment: [Sketch](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) is still Sketch (Mac) and still developed. Pencil may or may not be developed anymore since it's [open-source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pencil-planner/).

Comment: does Artboard have enough capabilities to handle most drawing? it seems a bit simple, such as only having a simple "pencil" option to draw...

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same Artboard. Check [this](http://tinyurl.com/okv9e4a) video tutorial and the [official](http://tinyurl.com/olycz6u) image tutorials.

(Not sure why I'm not getting post notifications on my e-mail, I just saw your question when browsing StackExchange on another matter).

Comment: sorry, i meant it didn't seem to have things like brushes.

Answer (score 2):

For vector drawing, on both Mac and iPads, iDraw works extremely well. However, it is not for diagramming; no rubber band lines, etc.

From the features you looked for it supports:

- editing existing shapes
- adding text anywhere
- SVG, PNG export (no maps though)
- it has tablet support (
- it can import other images into the drawing but can not vectorize raster images

Comment: Does it have many of the above features?

Answer (score 1):

[Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) is more of an image editor, but it actually got a [fairly big update recently](http://www.pixelmator.com/blog/2013/05/08/pixelmator-2-2-is-available-today-from-the-mac-app-store/) that added a lot of vector tools. There's a free trial, and the full version is only $14.99, probably worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Not for drawing but for diagraming. [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) it's a Java app that supports many types of diagrams. It's free.